# LINQ - Specified cast is not valid with dataview use

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I am trying to get the presence of rows based on the passed col. The column is coming from the database as MultiSelect.

```
bool bCFPresent = IsMultiSelectCFPresent(dvDataTag, "MultiSelect");


public static bool IsPresent(DataView dvDataTag, string colName)
{
  return ((from DataRowView drv in dvDataTag
                     where drv.Row.Field<short>(colName) == 1
                     select drv).Count() > 0 ? true : false);  
}
```

But I am getting this error:-

> System.InvalidCastException was
>   unhandled by user code
>   Message="Specified cast is not valid."
>   Source="System.Data.DataSetExtensions"
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object
>   value)
>          at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow
>   row, String columnName)

Please help .

Comment: What type is 'colName' in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the type of the column named `colName` can't be casted to a short...
Overall, your code doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense. The number of rows is the same for each column. Instead, try to check for the column directly, e.g like this:

```
public static bool IsPresent(DataView dvDataTag, string colName)
{
    return dvDataTag.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                      Any(c => c.ColumnName == colName);
}
```

Comment: This col is coming as either value 0 or 1 in the dataset. Something weird is happening..

Comment: I want to get the row count where colName value is 1.

Comment: so, what you really want is: `select count(*) from table where colName = 1`? This should be working with your original code. Maybe try using `int` instead of `short`?

Comment: I don't know your database, so I really can't say any more.

Comment: i just checked again with using int. In some places, it is working fine and at some places it is giving the same error. Although, i am returning it as 0 or 1 from the db. Not sure, why this is behaving erratic?

Comment: Are you always providing the same value to `colName`?

Comment: No, I mean: Does the variable `colName` always contain the same column name?

Comment: The problem might be, that it does not only contain 0 and 1 but also NULL. Is this a possibility?

Comment: it cannot be null. It will be either 1 or 0.

Comment: Then I have no idea left, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do in your predicate

```
drv.Row.Field<short>(colName) == 1
```

But your `IsPresent` Method can be rewritten as

**Update:**

```
public static bool IsPresent(DataView dvDataTag, string colName)
{

        return dvDataTag.Any(drv => string.Equals("1",drv[colName].ToString()));
}
```

For the Row Count

```
int count =  dvDataTag.Count(drv => string.Equals("1",drv[colName].ToString()));
```

**PS:** Handling of nulls is left to the OP

Comment: drv need not be defined. Isn't that the fun of using lamdas ? :)

Comment: i tried to use the row count code given by you. But it is giving this error. Error 2 'System.Data.DataView' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Karan have you included [System.Linq namespace ?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx)