# LINQ on a DataView

Tags: linq, ado.net, dataview

I cannot query a `DataView` without casting. The two lines of code in the method IsPresent are taken from *"[LINQ - Specified cast is not valid with dataview use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882062/linq-specified-cast-is-not-valid-with-dataview-use)"* and seem to work for everyone, except for one commenter. I am "using" the LINQ namespace, so what is my problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // works
            DataView o = new DataView();
            var p = from x in o.Cast<DataRowView>() where x.Row.Field<bool>("xxx") select x.Row;
        }

        public static bool IsPresent(DataView dvDataTag, string colName)
        {
            // does not work
            int count = dvDataTag.Count(drv => string.Equals("1", drv[colName].ToString())); 
            return dvDataTag.Any(drv => string.Equals("1", drv[colName].ToString()));
        } 

    }
}
```

Error   2   'System.Data.DataView' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) A:\TEMP\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  ConsoleApplication1 20  20

Answer (score 2):

try casting the table as you did in the Main method as such:

```
            int count = dvDataTag.OfType<DataRowView>().Count(drv => string.Equals("1", drv[colName].ToString()));
        return dvDataTag.OfType<DataRowView>().Any(drv => string.Equals("1", drv[colName].ToString()));
```

I also tried `.Cast<DataRowView>()` as in your Main method, and that also compiled.

Comment: As a side comment, I just added .OfType<DataRowView>() to your code.  I have no idea how it will behave with real data.

Comment: Thanks, but others do not need to cast, so I am wondering why I have to cast. I must be missing something.

Comment: Others also have to cast but do it implicitly e.g. like this "(from DataRowView drv in dvDataTag select drv).Any()"

Comment: I am not positive, but I think that the need to cast in this case is a safety net put into place to avoid any loss in data that could be incurred if a cast is made implicitly and unconsciously.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `DataView` implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` ( [Does LINQ work with IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7757365/530545) ). On top of that, it's a bit more confusing simply because the `DataView` enumerator returns objects of type `DataRowView`.

Use the `.Cast<DataRowView>()` Linq method because you know they're all of that type. Technically you can get away with `.OfType<DataRowView>()`, but be aware that it will silently ignore any objects in the collection that aren't of that type, while `Cast` will throw an exception ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015967/530545 ).